# tcl list lsearch wildcard override

Tags: tcl, wildcard

I have a tcl list of pairs like this; one of which has (*)star as the second element.

{ff 122} {ff 1} {fg 1} {ff *} {fg *}  --->var1

now I want to search the pair {fg *} using

```
lsearch $var1 [list "fg" "*"]
```

but it wrongly shows 2 {fg 1} instead of 4 {fg *} as the * is acting as a wildcard identifier. I can not override this using /* or {*} . Can any one help me with this overriding problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsearch` allows you to select the algorithm used for string matching. The default is `-glob` which does wildcard expansion of `*`. But you can also chose `-exact` for plain string matching or `-regexp` for regular expressions:

```
lsearch -exact $var1 "fg *"
```

or

```
lsearch -regexp $var1 {fg \*}
```

or even

```
lsearch -regexp $var1 {fg\s*\*}
```

Depending on what you actually intend to do.

See: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm

Comment: To the person who edited my code: while your edit was valid the original code was equally valid. `fg \*` is a perfectly good regex.

Answer (score -1):

```
lsearch -inline -all $var1 "fg \\\*"
```

Comment: but the result of this line is the first wrongly matched list. what I want is to know if the pair with star is present or not.

Comment: oh my bad.. i interpreted wrong. corrected the code. @Codename_DJ kindky check it.

Comment: You do know that you can avoid the quoting hell by using `{fg \*}` don't you?

Comment: yes. i guess both meant same @slebetman. It will work. I just gave the different answer from yours. All your answers were perfect. just i added one more.. :)